# How to add csrf token id redirect()->action

Tags: laravel, csrf

i have the below codeblock :

```
 return redirect()->action('mycontroller@myfunction',
              [
                  'data0' => $request->data0,
                  'data1' => $request->data1,
                  'data2' => $request->data2,
                  'data3' => $request->data3,

]);
```

Error shown :  **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** probably because csrf token is not passed through this route which is a post route.

```
Route::post('congrats', 'mycontroller@myfunction');
```

I don't want the data0, data1 etc values to be shown in the url so that's why i want it to be a POST.

**How can i pass the csrf token on a redirect action**? Is there any alternative way? For example using GET but hiding the specific data?

Comment: What about flashing the data to the session and having them available on the action you redirect to?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `VerifyCsrfToken` class like this to disable verification to your routes

```
  protected $except_urls = [
        'contact/create',
        'contact/update',
        ...
    ];

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $regex = '#' . implode('|', $this->except_urls) . '#';

    if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request) || preg_match($regex, $request->path()))
    {
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
    }

    throw new TokenMismatchException;
}
```

And change in Kernel to point the new middleware :

```
protected $middleware = [
...

    'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
];
```

[source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-disable-csrf-middleware-on-certain-routes)

**EDIT**

in laravel docs

add this to `VerifyCsrfToken` class

```
 protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
    ];
```

Comment: Is there a solution without editing `VerifyCsrfToken` or anything else?

Comment: you can disable Verify Csrf Token and then create a route group for all your other routes